# How can I get better ratings when drawing spells?

Tags: wizards-unite

In Wizards Unite, when we draw spells, there is a meter on the top of the screen. We can see if we got good, great, etc.

I want to know, how is this score calculated?

- I think the time taken to draw the spell is taken into account.
- I guess how well the drawn spell respects the shape also has an effect on the score.

Is there anything more I should know or look to?

In Pokemon GO, we could make the ball spin before throwing and timing it, and we could get exceptional often. Is there also a trick to drawing spells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, speed and accuracy are the key factors when casting spells. [This Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=np7jJ-bckXM) video does a great job explaining the importance of the two, and below are the highlights on how they effect the trace meter.

**Speed**
The meter will start decreasing the moment you being your tracing. The meter will continue to decrease until your finger is released from the screen.

**Accuracy**
If your spell was successfully drawn, then the meter will increase or decrease based on how accurate you were. If the trace is accurate, the meter will increase. However, if the trace is way off target, it may decrease the meter even further

As you draw, you may notice the trace line is green as some points. This means that portion was the most accurate it could be (despite it may be little off the line by a little).

**Potions**
The Youtube video didn't cover this, but another factor to keep in mind is potions. There are some potions, such as the [Wideye](https://wizardsunitehub.info/potion/wideye-potion/), that will help improve the speed and accuracy of your trace

Answer (score 1):

@Wondercricket's answer is already pretty accurate. 
I've just wanted to add that according to https://wizardsunite.gamepress.gg/beginners/qa-wizards-unite-gameplay#spellscore, the meter has mostly no influence on the chance of your spell to break the confoundable. This is only dependent on the base color of the meter that normally doesn't change.
In rare cases the meter has two colors. In this case bringing the indicator into the rightmost color DOES improve your chances.
The color seems to be the same as visible in the 'danger-meter' when selecting a potion to use (rounded to presumably 3 modes, orange, yellow and green). This means using a potion can also change the color of the meter.

The quality of the spell DOES also have influence over how much XP you gain, so there is still a benefit to casting great/masterful spells.